# Data table in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, database, datatable

I have a problem related to DataTable in .net.
i am trying to fill datatable on page_load .that part is ok no issue datatable correctly filled up with data. but I noticed that when I clicked button on page... it again try to fill datatable which just a time-consuming task... I want datatable should fill once only ,when , when site open in browser .. not at every click ... because I have a large amount of data in table so it takes time to load in datatable.. 
plz help me out ... 
here is my code:

```
protectd void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        cnn.ConnectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

      //  if (this.IsPostBack == true)
        {
            dr1 = TableUtoP(); 
            dtWordsList.Load(dr1);
       }
}

OleDbDataReader TableUtoPunj(String ArrWord)
    {
        if (cnn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            cnn.Close();
        }
        cnn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT U, P from UtoP";
        cmd.Connection = cnn;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return dr;
    }
```

Comment: There are so many things wrong with that code, that I think what you really need is a basic C# course.

Comment: Are you by any chance reloading the table on every postback because you're losing its contents between posts?

Comment: Question names should not include tags (C#, .NET) and should describe the problem. I was going to edit it however if I remove the tags then your title would just be DataTable...

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the page is posting back or not, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnn.ConnectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;

    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        // This will only happen when the page is first loaded, as the first time is not considered a post back, but all others are
        dr1 = TableUtoP(); 
        dtWordsList.Load(dr1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks ... i tried it out already (commented code in question).. but does not helped out.. initially when page starts ...by default postback is false and it entered in if condition and fill the datatable ... but when i clicked on button .. that time postback is true and i did not tried to fill DTs ... after that it shows that DT has no data...

Answer (score 0):

Only fill the dataTable if it's not a PostBack...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        //TO DO: Make the call to fill the data table here
   }
}
```